# Как предотвратить одновременное открытие нескольких программ на golang?

Tags: golang

Нужно сделать,  что если программа уже запущена, что б повторная копия не запускалась.
Как такое сделать на golang?

Comment: В виндовсе кто разрабатывает оконные программки на чистом WinAPI, если не ошибаюсь, обычно проверяют регистрацию класса своего окна. Если есть - значит уже одна копия программы работает. В распространённых фреймвёрках это уже встроенная функция. Если в голанге нет такой, то надо углубиться до WINAPI или придумать свой способ наследить своей программой, чтобы было видно что она работает. В линухе например pid-файлы оставляют в условленном месте. И потом проверяют их наличие и жив ли процесс чей id там записан. В крайнем случае и в виндовсе можно проделать тоже самое.

Answer (score 1):

Сохраняй в рабочем каталоге программы при запуске файл с PID. Но перед этим проверяй что в системе нет процесса с этим PID, если есть - ты говорим что копия запущена.

[Getpid](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getpid) - текущий PID процесса.

[FindProcess](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FindProcess) - поиск процесса по PID, правда под UNIX всегда возвращает os.Process независимо от того существует он или нет, и надо будет проверить реально ли существует этот процесс (спросить текущий PID?).

Comment: Как атомизировать чтение и запись файла?

Comment: Только обходными путями. Например, создать еще один файл с помощью
// BEGIN critical section
lock_file, err := os.OpenFile("/tmp/mylock.lock", flag int, os.O_CREATE | os. O_EXCL)
if err != nil {
    //мы не одни//
}
// создать PID файл
err := os.Remove("/tmp/mylock.lock")
// END critical section

Ключевой момент тут - "os.O_CREATE | os. O_EXCL"

Comment: Либо воспользоваться чем то готовым типа https://godoc.org/github.com/nightlyone/lockfile#example-Lockfile

Answer (score 0):

Можно открывать файл в монопольном режиме. Если открылся - хорошо и работаешь. Нет - значит программа уже запущена.

Пример для windows можно посмотреть тут: https://github.com/rekby/lockrun/blob/master/lockrun_windows.go

для linux можно посмотреть http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/lockrun.c - код на C, но простой.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от ОС нужно использовать разные команды для получения списка процессов но суть примерно одинаковая:

```
func isProcRunning(names ...string) (bool, string, error) {
    if len(names) == 0 {
        return false, "", nil
    }

    cmd := exec.Command("tasklist.exe", "/fo", "csv", "/nh")
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: false}
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        return false, "", err
    }

    for _, name := range names {
        if bytes.Contains(out, []byte(name)) {
            return true, name, nil
        }
    }
    return false, "", nil
}
```

1. Передаешь в функуию имя/имена(можно по PID в зависимости от того, что удобнее) процесса
2. запускаешь утилиту которая открывает список всех процессов(с необходимыми флагами)
3. Ишешь в оутпуте утилиты нужные имена или Id

Пример использования:

```
func main() {
    isRunning, name, _ := isProcRunning("excel.exe")
    fmt.Println("Is excel.exe running: ", isRunning)
    isRunning, name, _ = isProcRunning("iexplore.exe", "firefox.exe", "chrome.exe")
    flag := false
    switch name {
    case "iexplore.exe":
        fmt.Println("Is iexplore.exe running: ", isRunning)
        fmt.Println("Is firefox.exe running: ", flag)
        fmt.Println("Is chrome.exe running: ", flag)
        break
    case "firefox.exe":
        fmt.Println("Is iexplore.exe running: ", flag)
        fmt.Println("Is firefox.exe running: ", isRunning)
        fmt.Println("Is chrome.exe running: ", flag)
        break
    case "chrome.exe":
        fmt.Println("Is iexplore.exe running: ", flag)
        fmt.Println("Is firefox.exe running: ", flag)
        fmt.Println("Is chrome.exe running: ", isRunning)
        break
    default:
        fmt.Println("Is iexplore.exe running: ", flag)
        fmt.Println("Is firefox.exe running: ", flag)
        fmt.Println("Is chrome.exe running: ", flag)
    }

}
```

[Найдено на Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2lkz3i/best_way_to_get_process_list_on_windows/)